# Twitter OAuth 2.0 working in simulator but not in real device

Tags: swift, twitter-oauth, urlsession

I am working on [Twitter v2](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/user-access-token) and to get a accessToken I need to call an API. This is the API call I am doing in my swift code:

```
let combinedCredentials = “client_id:client_Secret"
        
guard let inputData = combinedCredentials.data(using: .utf8) else {
    return
}

let authorizationHeader = "Basic \(inputData.base64EncodedString())”
let code = //generated from another endpoint
let redirectURI = appscheme + "://"
let codeVerifier = "challenge"
        
let url = URL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/2/oauth2/token")!
        
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue(authorizationHeader, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
let body = "code=\(code!)&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=\(redirectURI)&code_verifier=\(codeVerifier)"
request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    //Gives 400 error in actual device but working in postman and simulator
}
task.resume()
```

The problem I am facing is that this api gives success(getting access token) when I run it in postman and simulator(17.0) but gives 400 error when I run an actual device. I have tested in iOS 15 and iOS 17 device. The error I am getting is

> "error": invalid_request, "error_description": Missing required parameter [client_id]

I tried encoding the redirectURI but still this gives 400 in device and works in simulator. I know that if it is working in simulator that means the parameters I am sending is correct and I think that the issue is somewhere in the request call but I am not able to figure out the issue. Is there anything wrong with the API call?

Comment: Could you check maybe with POSTMAN to generate a cURL code or even Swift code to help compare? Unrelated, but you can avoid the `guard let inputData = combinedCredentials.data(using: .utf8)` with `let imputData = Data(combinedCredentials.utf8)`. I don't see "client_id" params in body, as the error says so. Is that normal? So it's thinking you're trying to use a public client instead of a confidential one?